# How to allow suscriber to access specific pages in dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, admin

I want to create some pages in admin dashboard which are also shown to subscribers. Normally subscriber can see dashboard page and profile only. I want to create a page called Orders and show to subscribers. But not other pages.

How can I do ?

Thanks in Advance.

```
**I POSTED HERE BECAUSE FOUND NO ANSWER IN WORDPRESS EXCHANGE**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_menu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()` to create your custom menu. 
You can set the `$capability` parameter to `read` to make them available to subscribers.

From WordPress codex:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page